# NFC auto tag detection on new activity

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard

I am trying to read an nfc card in my project. The process is First you'll tap the card and it'll take you to the next activity. Then the read nfc tag should automatically fire the read command for nfc. But what happens is that I have to tap again the card to fire the command. Is there a way to read the card again in a new activity without tapping it? Like when the new activity starts it automatically reads the card?

Comment: why don't you pass the data to the next activity?

Comment: @muratgu - I already did and I'm looking for other ways to know which one is better or more efficient than the others.

Comment: @Jujumancer as muratgu said you have to read data in 1rst activity and send it to 2nd activity